# A string as part of an expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass a part of an expression as an argument as a string? Something like this:

```js
let t = "val";
$('.class').t();
```

UPD

[image]

[image]

UPD 2

My mistake, I was just redefining an already declared variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) to access the property of an object dynamically:

```
let t = "val";
$('.class')[t]();
```

This will call the method with the name that matches the value of the t variable on the jQuery object with the class. If the method exists on the object, it will be called with the appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

you want this slove?

```
$('.class')[t]();
```